# Form in Form is not allowed, but what else

Tags: php, forms, submit

I fetch SQL data with a while loop and insert the data into a table. With a form and a  submit button i can save modified values.

*My simplified code:*

```
 <table>
        <tr>
    <?php
//SQL QUERY
//...

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql_header)) {
    $var_ab = $row['ab'];
    $var_id = $row['id'];
?>
          <form id="form1" action="" method="POST">
             <td> 
                   <input type="text" value="<?php echo $var_ab; ?>" 
             </td>
             <td>
                   <input type="text" value="<?php echo $var_id; ?>" 
             </td>
       //PLACEHOLDER FOR SECOND FORM
       <?php
}
?>

        </tr>  
             <td>
                 <input type="submit" name="save" value="SAVE" class="classsubmit" />
             </td>
        </form>
       </tr>
    </table>
```

So far, so good. So, how can I insert a second form to delete an entry? I've tried to place this code (PLACEHOLDER FOR SECOND FORM - see above)

```
<td>
<form id="form2" action="" method="POST">
       <input type="text" value="<?php echo $var_id;?>" 
</form>
</td>
```

but it's not working and it's not allowed to nest forms.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you only want to delete an entry on the page or in the database you could try a button or a span with an onclick function.
for example:

```
    <span onclick="window.location='?delete=<?php echo $row[(unique-value-in-database-from-this-row)]; ?>'; return false">Delete entry</span>
```

Make sure you add return false or the first form will be submitted. If you use a button make sure it has type="button"

On this page could be a PHP code like this:

```
   if(isset($_GET['delete']))
   {
      $item = $_GET['delete'];
   //SQL connect
      $result = mysql_query($conection ,"DELETE FROM table WHERE uniquevalue='$item'");
   }
```

I hope gives an idea for a solution.